# Access control implementation with custom rules

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, auth0, rbac, idp

I am building a security module(authentication and authorization) for a B2B SaaS based application. We have a straightforward authentication mechanism i.e with username and password with MFA. however, the authorization part is a little complicated The rule is something like below:

we have 2 domain objects lets call it D1 and D2. D2 is a child of D1 with a mapping as One to many from D1 to D2. Both D1 and D2 have other domain objects or modules linked but access on them can be computed based on access on D1 or D2. now for the authorization part we have 3 levels of roles required. The level 1 roles are unaware of any domain objects like a global_admin who can perform any action on a platform. The level 2 roles needs to be aware of D1 identifier and they can only operate on the resources directly linked to these D1 objects, same is the case for level 3 role where the underlying domain object will be D3.

There is also an another term called permission groups. so whenever we are assigning all of these 3 roles to the user then we are saving that to a permission groups and thus user is not diectly mapped to roles but through a intermediate layer called permission groups so that we can reuse the previous permission groups for other users and if any changes required we will do that to the permission group and effect will be applicable to all the linked users.

Server is written with spring boot and security is handled via spring security. I was exploring the possibility of implementing this with identity providers like Auth0.

Whats the possible way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

For the 1st level of roles, this is just traditional RBAC: association of a role to users and access control based on this role. Auth0 supports roles and so does Spring security (they call it `GrantedAuthority`). All you have to do is to provide a `Converter<Jwt, ? extends Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>>` and use it in a `Converter<Jwt, JwtAuthenticationToken>`. Something like that:

```java
static class AuthoritiesConverter implements Converter<Jwt, List<SimpleGrantedAuthority>> {
    @Override
    public List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> convert(Jwt source) {
        final List<String> auth0Roles = (List<String>) source.getClaims().getOrDefault("roles", List.of());
        return auth0Roles.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).toList();
    }
}

@Bean
SecurityFilterChain filterChain(
        HttpSecurity http,
        Converter<Jwt, ? extends Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>> authoritiesConverter) throws Exception {
    http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> 
        oauth2.jwt(jwtResourceServer -> 
            jwtResourceServer.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwt -> 
                new JwtAuthenticationToken(
                        jwt,
                        authoritiesConverter.convert(jwt),
                        jwt.getClaimAsString(StandardClaimNames.SUB)))));

    ...

    return http.build();
}
```

For the 2nd and 3rd levels, I see two options depending on the cardinality between users and D1 or D2:

- if the number of entities a user can be linked to fits in a JWT (JWTs size is not limited but it is transported in HTTP headers and most servers set a limit for headers to about 8kb), I would:

  - expose a REST endpoint with the list of D1 and D2 a given user can access
  - write an Auth0 action to call this endpoint when a user logs in
  - add the result as private claim to the access token
  - define an `Authentication` of my own (instead of `JwtAuthenticationToken`, using `AbstractAuthenticationToken` as base class) with methods to hide the details of private claims access and make SpEL syntax lighter.
- if the cardinality is too high, then I'd expose an authorization service taking an `Authentication` instance and D1 or D2 identifier as parameter and returning a boolean for access. As you can reference a bean in SpEL, calling such a service is trivial.

In any case, the `authentication` "magic" variable in SpEL as well as reference to `@PathVariable` will be of great help when writing `@PreAuthorize` expressions.

The solution with the private claim in the JWT has a great advantage: database access to get association between a user and D1, D2 occurs only once per token issuance, which will make it scale much better.

```java
@RequestMapping("/d1s")
@RestController
public class D1Controller {

    @GetMapping("/{d1Id}/by-private-claim")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('roleLevel1') || authentication.canReadD1(#d1.id)")
    public D1 getD1WithAccessByPrivateClaim(@PathVariable(name = "d1Id") D1 d1) {
        return d1;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{d1Id}/using-authorization-service-bean")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('roleLevel1') || @authorizationService.canReadD1(authentication, #d1.id)")
    public D1 getD1WithAccessByAuthorizationService(@PathVariable(name = "d1Id") D1 d1) {
        return d1;
    }
}
```

First method requires to provide an `Authentication` with a `canReadD1` method (working with private claims), second method requires to provide with an `authorizationService` bean with a `canReadD1` method (working with database).